Why is my RxJS merge subscription firing when no observables have emitted values?
I have Angular code like this which listens to changes on multiple fields and then saves the changes when any of them change. The problem is that the story is getting saved even though nothing is being logged to the console, which means no observables should have fired. Why is the save getting called and how can I debug this?
    merge([
        this.form.get('storyName').valueChanges.pipe(tap(x => console.log('storyName', x))),
        this.form.get('storyTypeId').valueChanges.pipe(tap(x => console.log('storyTypeId', x))),
        this.form.get('backlogId').valueChanges.pipe(tap(x => console.log('backlogId', x))),
        this.form.get('ownerUserId').valueChanges.pipe(tap(x => console.log('ownerUserId', x))),
        this.form.get('points').valueChanges.pipe(tap(x => console.log('points', x))),
        this.form.get('tags').valueChanges.pipe(tap(x => console.log('tags', x))),
      ]).pipe(
        debounceTime(300),
      ).subscribe(async () => {
        try {
          await this.saveStory();
        } finally {
          this.isSavingStory = false;
        }
      });


Can you reproduce this in a Stackblitz? (I couldn't) Also, how is Angular Material relevant here?

@Cuzy, you're right, I meant just Angular. I removed the material tag.

If think the only problem in your code is that you passed an array to the merge operator instead of declaring the inner obervables one after the other :
I believe this should work :
merge(
  this.form.get('storyName').valueChanges.pipe(tap(x => console.log('storyName', x))),
  this.form.get('storyTypeId').valueChanges.pipe(tap(x => console.log('storyTypeId', x))),
  this.form.get('backlogId').valueChanges.pipe(tap(x => console.log('backlogId', x))),
  this.form.get('ownerUserId').valueChanges.pipe(tap(x => console.log('ownerUserId', x))),
  this.form.get('points').valueChanges.pipe(tap(x => console.log('points', x))),
  this.form.get('tags').valueChanges.pipe(tap(x => console.log('tags', x))),
).pipe(
  debounceTime(300),
).subscribe(async () => {
  try {
    await this.saveStory();
  } finally {
    this.isSavingStory = false;
  }
});

I'd also like you give you a tip, you can use the controls property from a FormGroup to get a nice autocompletion when trying to access the contained form controls by name :
merge(
  this.form.controls.storyName.valueChanges.pipe(tap(x => console.log('storyName', x))),
  this.form.controls.storyTypeId.valueChanges.pipe(tap(x => console.log('storyTypeId', x))),
  this.form.controls.backlogId.valueChanges.pipe(tap(x => console.log('backlogId', x))),
  this.form.controls.ownerUserId.valueChanges.pipe(tap(x => console.log('ownerUserId', x))),
  this.form.controls.points.valueChanges.pipe(tap(x => console.log('points', x))),
  this.form.controls.tags.valueChanges.pipe(tap(x => console.log('tags', x))),
).pipe(
  debounceTime(300),
).subscribe(async () => {
  try {
    await this.saveStory();
  } finally {
    this.isSavingStory = false;
  }
});

Hope this helps !
Edit:
The merge operator can be used to merge observable with non observable values, thus why it accepted the array, but it never tried to subscribe to it.
A good example of this behaviour would be a simple merge that combine an observable with an array of string :
merge(
  ['a value', 'another value'], 
  of('hello')
).subscribe(console.log);

In this small example, all values in the merge operator will be logged ('a value', 'another value', 'hello')
You can test this behaviour in this StackBlitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-eyje1l?file=index.ts

Why does merge offer an overload that accepts an array and why did it cause the issue I was having?

The merge operator can take variables that are not observable, but it wont subscribe to them.
In your case the array is not an observable and thus was never subscribed, but if you'd added a console log in your subscribe, you'd see that the array is still emited, I've updated my answer.

Try removing the array, instead just pass the valueChanges as arguments to the merge:
...
merge(
  this.form
    .get('input')!
    .valueChanges.pipe(tap((x) => console.log('input', x))),
  this.form
    .get('select')!
    .valueChanges.pipe(tap((x) => console.log('select', x))),
  this.form
    .get('textarea')!
    .valueChanges.pipe(tap((x) => console.log('textarea', x)))
)
...

Full code
TS:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { tap, debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { merge } from 'rxjs';

/** @title Simple form field */
@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'form-field-overview-example.html',
  styleUrl: 'form-field-overview-example.css',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
})
export class FormFieldOverviewExample {
  isSavingStory = false;
  form = new FormGroup({
    input: new FormControl(''),
    select: new FormControl(''),
    textarea: new FormControl(''),
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    merge(
      this.form
        .get('input')!
        .valueChanges.pipe(tap((x) => console.log('input', x))),
      this.form
        .get('select')!
        .valueChanges.pipe(tap((x) => console.log('select', x))),
      this.form
        .get('textarea')!
        .valueChanges.pipe(tap((x) => console.log('textarea', x)))
    )
      .pipe(debounceTime(300))
      .subscribe(() => {
        try {
          console.log('saveStory');
        } finally {
          this.isSavingStory = false;
        }
      });
  }
}

HTML:
<form [formGroup]="form">   <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Input</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="input" />   </mat-form-field>   <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Select</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="select">
      <mat-option value="one">First option</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="two">Second option</mat-option>
    </mat-select>   </mat-form-field>   <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Textarea</mat-label>
    <textarea matInput formControlName="textarea"></textarea>   </mat-form-field> </form>

Stackblitz Demo

There is no overload where merge accepts an array, it only accepts multiple values, where 1 value is an array, we need to pass an observable. It's our responsibility, basically.
This is the output type when you pass an array:
merge<[Observable<string | null>]>(sources_0: ObservableInput<Observable<string | null>>): Observable<Observable<string | null>>

So it returns an observable of observable, so it does not work.

Why does merge offer an overload that accepts an array and why did it cause the issue I was having?
